# How can I do a message notification bar?

Tags: android, notifications

What special function that can send messages to all who have the application installed? Message that appears on the notification bar. And only appears once, when sent.

Is there an example?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: I thank you a lot more now doing research, I can implant. Thank you again